# jquery, modifying a plugin's options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to change a plugin's options, on the fly.  But I cannot find how that's accomplished.  Though, I'm positive I've seen it done before.

here's a simple plugin with 1 option:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change_the_option(40)">click me</a>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(#menu).animateMenu({
            padding:20
        })

    });

function change_the_option(valchange){

 //somehow modify the option here, I'm guessing

}
```

That is loaded with the page, automatically.  However, I may wish to change the padding option dynamically, without reloading the entire page.

Basically, if someone clicks a link or any selector I choose, I want to change padding:20 to padding:40, or whatever.

Does anyone have experience with modifying plugin options, on the fly?

Comment: Usually the plugin will have a way of doing this.  Which plugin is this, or is it something you've created?

Comment: It's one I've created. Well, sort of. I'm working on creating one. 
I simply grabbed the first simple example I could find.

Comment: its your plugin. you can make it adjust anyway you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, have a look at

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

from "Defaults and Option" on down to the end.  Ideally you would want to be able to call your plugin passing some parameters to do what you want.  For instance:

```
$("#menu").animateMenu("padding","20")
```

or

```
$("#menu").animateMenu("update",{padding:20})
```

Up to you exactly how you want it to work, but it should return the jquery object so that it ca be properly chained.  This is all explained in the above link.

But in this way, you could have nice clean code, that you could chain along with other jquery, like so:

```
$("#menu").animateMenu();  // initialize the menu

// ... do other stuff

$("#menu").animateMenu("update",{padding:20}).css("color","red");

// ... etc.
```

Comment: can you give an example of how to the "update" method should be? i can't seem to access options from the "init" method.

Comment: @whyzee have a look at the "Namespacing" section of the above link.

Answer (score 4):

This question bothered me for a while, and this is one of the work around I found. Works for me. English is not my first language, so pardon me if I don't explain it clearly.

This is one plugin I created for toggle switch before.

In the `init` method, I saved the plugin options to `jQuery.data()`, and then later on, I can call the `simpleSwitchUpdate` function with new options. As you can see, I retrieve the old options saved for the element and call the `$.extend` to compose new options, and just call the `$.fn.simpleSwitch` with the `newOptions`. I have been using this pattern for creating updatable plugins for a while and it works pretty well for me.

```
/**
 *  A plugin for switch
 */

(function($) {

    var Switch = {

        init : function(options, elm) {
            var self = this;
            self.$elm = $(elm);

            self.$elm.empty();
            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.simpleSwitch.options, options);

            self.$elm.data("switchData", self.options);
            self.$elm.append(self.createSwitch());

        },

        createSwitch : function() {

           //logic to create your plugin
        }
    };

    $.fn.simpleSwitch = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var simpleSwitch = Object.create(Switch);
            simpleSwitch.init(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.simpleSwitchUpdate = function(options) {
        var switchData = this.data("switchData");
        var newOptions;
        if (switchData) {
            newOptions = $.extend({}, switchData, options);
        } else {
            newOptions = $.extend({}, $.fn.simpleSwitch.options, options);
        }

        return this.simpleSwitch(newOptions);
    };

    $.fn.simpleSwitch.options = {
        width : 25,
        height : 15,
        on : true,
        onDirection : "right",
        easing : "easeOutQuint",
        roundBorder : true,
        onColor : "orange",
        offColor : "lightgray",
        onToggle : null
    };

})(jQuery);
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ever0702/nmftyau3/4)

Comment: It would be nice to provide a snippet of this in action :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ever0702/nmftyau3/4/  not a very nice example, just proof of concept, you can update the switch after the switch is initialized

Comment: You can embed that in your answer right here, if you like

Answer (score 0):

For doing that, plugin must return a reference to its internal class. So, you can store it and call it later, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var animateMenu = $('#menu').animateMenu({
        padding:20
    })
});
```

and later:

`animateMenu.add(something);` or `animateMenu.setOptions({ padding: 30 });` (or whatever).

But this breaks the jQuery chainability, so, you must decide what is better for you. Another option is including some argument telling about returning it or not, like jQuery Tools do, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var animateMenu = $('#menu').animateMenu({
        api:true
    })
});
```

I made my first plugin analyzing the code of jQuery Tools Tabs, maybe it could help you.
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

PS: most selectors must be quoted, check your code.